# Keeping fingers (not just hand) on the rifle

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

Concerning the first/third person characters in Unreal...

I've seen many posts saying that inverse kinematics is the way to go for keeping the left hand on the character.

This keeps the left hand on the rifle but the fingers of the hand bob in and out of the rifle as it moves with the animation.

What is the best way to go about keeping the fingers realistically stabilized on the rifle as the animation moves the body ever so slightly?

If the answer is create a new animation in blender or a similar software, is it possible to import the animations from Unreal to blender and work with them there?  If so, can you please provide a way to do so?  Every time I've tried to the body doesn't appear, just the bones.

Thanks.

Comment: Use IK to lock the entire hand to the rifle, which I presume would extend to the fingers also moving with the rifle, then just solve from the wrist back to your character.

Comment: Sorry, can you be a bit more specific when you say solve from the wrist back to the character?

Comment: Huh?  This is exactly what inverse kinematics is!  Maybe you should add detail to your question about exactly how you're currently using IK.  Maybe you're only pinning the position of the hand and not the rotation.  You show no code, so we can only guess.

Comment: There are some helper nodes for using Epic Games' included IK functions to assign the position of nodes between two nodes with already-known position

Answer (score 0):

You have to make aninations outside unreal.
In blender or maya or the choice of your software.

To export an asset from UE4:

- In the content browser
- Select the asset you want to export.
- Then right click on this asset
- You will see an option called Asset action.
- Click on export.

Then import it in blender. For the rest there are tutorials and you can google.